# How to Create Random Points Within a Polygon (Vector Layer)

Tags: qgis, polygon, layers, point, sampling

I have a vector layer that covers a few acres of land, with the buildings cut out (so essentially just the soil in the area). I want to generate points within this defined area. Later, I will use my `random point sampling` plugin to do so. I can do that, but I cannot get the computer to make the points.

I go to `Vector -> Research -> Random Points`. From there, I select this layer and use it as the boundary. I want the result unstratified, but neither unstratified nor stratified seem to work. The program creates the corresponding files and new layer, but the points do not appear on the canvas. I have tried changing the appearance of the points to be more visible, but still cannot see them.

What have I done wrong? I am new to Quantum and trying to work out a few kinks.

Comment: Strange, please provide some screenshots of your workflow

Comment: QGIS version, operating system? In QGIS 2.18 it uses processing (GRASS), did you install them?

Comment: Another trick to try is to right click on the layer and select `zoom to layer`. This can help if something is being produced but in the wrong place - usually because you have a projection issue.

Comment: Are both the layers CRS and the Project CRS the same?